# Как спрятать информацию (пароли, url и пр.) в python

Tags: python

От совсем "залётных" пользователей использовал base64, чтобы пароли не были доступны невооруженному глазу:

```
password=base64.b64decode(postgres["password"])
```

Но считаю это костылём. Подскажите, как храните пароли вы.

Up1 Пример python-функция в postgresql - где идёт забор данных из БД с подключением и вводом пользователя и пароля. Как скрыть, "захэшить" пароль и т.п.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfucn1(w text)
   RETURNS SETOF login AS
$BODY$
from pymssql import connect as conn
q = tuple()
db = conn(host='00.0.00.00', database='core', user='sde', 
    password='12345', charset='UTF-8')
query = db.cursor()
query.execute(u"""query1""")
ss = query.fetchall()
for field1, field2 in ss:
    q += ([field1, field2],)
return q
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpythonu
```

Up2. Я понял, что хэширование используют при авторизациях и т.п., но как это применить в моём примере?

Comment: base64 вообще ни разу не шифрование. Что, где, от кого и зачем вы собираетесь прятать?

Comment: И зачем вы хотите хранить сами пароли, когда обычно достаточно хранить их хеши?

Comment: Пароли нужно хранить для того, чтобы можно было сравнивать тот же хэш. А если не хранить, то это означает, что пароль нужно вводить каждый раз, чтобы сравнить его хэш.

Answer (score 10):

Для хеширования строк предназначен модуль hashlib. Прежде чем использовать функции из этого модуля, необходимо подключить модуль с помощью инструкции:

```
import hashlib
```

Модуль предоставляет следующие функции: md5(), sha1(), sha224(), sha256(), sha384 и sha512(). В качестве необязательного параметра функциям можно передать шифруемую последовательность байтов. Например:

```
import hashlib
h = hashlib.sha1(b"password")
```

Передать последовательность байтов можно также с помощью метода update(). В этом случае объект присоединяется к предыдущему значению:

```
h = hashlib.sha1()
h.update(b"password")
```

Получить зашифрованную последовательность байтов и строку позволяют два метода — digest() и hexdigest():

```
h = hashlib.sha1(b"password")
h.digest()
b'[\xaaa\xe4\xc9\xb9??\x06\x82%\x0b1\xf83\x1b~\xe6\x8f\xd9'
h.hexdigest()
'5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8'
```

Для сравнения введенного пользователем пароля с сохраненным в базе необходимо получить хеш введенного пароля, а затем произвести сравнение.

```
import hashlib
h = hashlib.md5(b"password")
p = h.hexdigest()
p    # Пароль, сохраненный в базе
'5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99'
h2 = hashlib.md5(b"password")   # Пароль, введенный пользователем
if p == h2.hexdigest(): print("Пароль правильный")
```

Программа выведет что пароль правильный.

**Также можно использовать:**

- [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html) -  MD5, SHA-1,SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512
- [pycrypto](http://www.pycrypto.org) - Python Cryptography Toolkit

Вдобавок к PyCrypto - [KeyCzar](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html), это чтобы было проще работать.

- RSA вот [пример](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html)

А также поиск по категориям: http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=401&c=400

Comment: `Для шифрования` – таки для хеширования, потому что зашифрованный текст можно расшифровать, а хеш нельзя. А в остальном — плюс.

Comment: отличный ответ с понятными примерами!

Comment: Еще можно добавить что к паролям перед хешированием хорошо добавлять соль -- какую-то последовательность символов. Если базу скомуниздят и попытаются по хешам восстановить пароли, то это может выйти, т.к. есть соответствующие сервисы с базой хешей, а соленые хеши намного сложнее взломать

Comment: Также стоит отметить, что есть специальные функции для хранения паролей/ключей разного рода. И это отнюдь не MD5 или SHA. В hashlib можно попробовать несколько (pbkdf2 и scrypt) из секции [Key derivation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#key-derivation), однако, там не все так просто с их доступностью и возможно придется что-то доустановить.

Comment: Пример с солью: `import bcrypt; hash = bcrypt.hashpw('12345', bcrypt.gensalt()); hash == bcrypt.hashpw('12345', hash);`